# mkl exception after installing anaconda accelerate

Tags: machine-learning, anaconda, theano, intel-mkl, passage

When trying to train an RNN using Passage I get the following exception when running: model = RNN(layers=layers, cost='bce')

Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Dot22(Reshape{2}.0, Reshape{2}.0), '\n', 'Compilation failed (return status=1): ld: library not found for -lmkl. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). ', '[Dot22(, )]')

This is a new issue since installing Anaconda Accelerate.

Appreciate any and all advice!